# How to compare "Fri Jul 1 05:21:23 2016" datetime format in perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a datetime value in the format "Fri Jul  1 05:21:23 2016", how can i compare this?

I need to do like `if($date1<$date2) { print "do something"! }`

Kindly help to find the answer!

Comment: [`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/~esaym/Time-Piece-1.31/Piece.pm#Date_Parsing)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3A%3AFormat%3A%3AStrptime) to parse the strings into [`Datetime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) objects that support comparisons:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y');

my $dt1 = $strp->parse_datetime("Fri Jul 1 05:21:23 2016");
my $dt2 = $strp->parse_datetime("Sat Jul 2 05:21:23 2016");    

if ($dt1 < $dt2) {  # or use DateTime->compare()
    say '$dt1 < $dt2';
}
elsif ($dt1 == $dt2) {
    say '$dt1 == $dt2';
}
else {
    say '$dt1 > $dt2';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) to convert your strings into objects that can be compared directly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $date1 = 'Fri Jul 1 05:21:23 2016';
my $date2 = 'Thu Jun 30 12:00:00 2016';

my $date_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y';

my $tp1 = Time::Piece->strptime($date1, $date_format);
my $tp2 = Time::Piece->strptime($date2, $date_format);

if ($tp1 < $tp2) {
  say "$date1 is before $date2";
} elsif ($tp1 > $tp2) {
  say "$date1 is after $date2";
} else {
  say "$date1 is the same as $date2";
}
```

Comment: Because I use `say()` in the program. Also 5.10 was the first version to include Time::Piece in the standard distribution (of course, users of earlier versions of Perl can install it from CPAN). But mainly, I suppose, because I consider Perl 5.10 to be the minimum acceptable version for serious Perl development.

Comment: I prefer to use `Datetime` & Co for date/time manipulation as it's kind of more universal. For instance, `Time::Piece` will happily accept `'Thu Jul 1 05:21:23 2016'` (note the day name), while `Datetime` won't.

Comment: I don't think that your example shows that DateTime is "more universal". I think it shows that Time::Piece does more error correction than DateTime :-) Both behaviours can be useful in certain circumstances and I use both modules regularly. I tend to use Time::Piece more in StackOverflow answers because of the large number of questions posed by people who claim they can't install modules from CPAN.